# Why do i need to configure an extra port for Websphere Application server

Tags: http, configuration, websphere, port

We use an Apache HTTP server with a Websphere Application Server 8.5

Requests to HTTP servers work on default port 80
I have configured port 2021 on http.conf + in default host in Websphere and everything works.  The only 'problem' i have is that we need port info in the URL.

http://oursite/index.html works
http://oursite/myApp.jsp doesn't work
When i add the portnumer to the request it works.

I understand that this extra port is needed to tell HTTP server that this request should be forwarded to Websphere.  But customers are complaining that the port we used is blocked by their firewall and some customers refuse to add this port to give access.

Now i tried to add port 80 to the Websphere config (default host) and this seems to work.

Is it really needed to config an additional port ?

Answer (score 3):

*:80 is in the "default_host" by default. Whatever host and port your clients will use to address the proxy must be present in the virtual host that your application is deployed to -- otherwise it won't be handled by the WAS Plug-in.

It sounds like someone removed that *:80 alias from the default host, mistakenly thinking it only needed to be there if the application server explicitly listened on port 80. That is misguided.